# An equivalent verb/idiom for "taping pieces together with saliva"

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

Is there a verb or idiom for "connecting heterogeneous pieces together in a fast and careless way to build something", which would be an antonymous phrase of "careful and systematic construction and integration of parts"?

In my mother tongue, we have an idiom that roughly translates to "sticking/taping pieces together with saliva", which is used in a negative manner. I was wondering if it has an equivalent.

Comment: Your proposed solution is a [***mishmash***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mishmash) of different ideas that don't really [***hang together***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hang%20together).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The English idiom that immediately comes to mind is “held/put together with spit and baling wire”. This phrase was the subject of a question on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/spit-and-baling-wire).

Comment: I've never heard that idiom myself. This ngram doesn't reveal many uses in English literature, either. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+spit+and+bailing+wire%2C+held+together+with+string&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20spit%20and%20bailing%20wire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheld%20together%20with%20string%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thanks @Astralbee! Given the similarities, it seems the idiom is surviving in other languages... :)

Comment: Looks like "spit and duct tape" is overtaking this phrase in popularity: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spit+and+baling+wire%2Cspit+and+duct+tape&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspit%20and%20baling%20wire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspit%20and%20duct%20tape%3B%2Cc0

Comment: See also bubble gum and prayers. There seems to be a wide overlap between "spit, bubble gum, baling wire, prayers and duct tape". They often show up in pairs: "Held together with bubblegum and prayers", "... with duct tape and baling wire" etc.

Comment: I think "spit and prayers" was what I was trying to think of, but any of these permutations would be clear enough to any speaker and seem directly analogous to OP's idiom.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Yes, "spit and a prayer". :)

Comment: Who needs spit when you have duct tape? :)

Comment: @chepner - Duct tape is like the Force: It has a light side and a dark side and it holds the universe together.

Comment: "Spit and baling wire" is exactly the idiom that came immediately to my mind. I'm curious why, if it is so rare according to ngrams. It's also a bit incongruous, because baling wire is quite strong and (properly applied) can hold things together very well, especially bales of hay.

Answer (score 7):

We might say that shoddily made things are 'held together with string'. This seems equivalent to your idiom. See [this headline](https://www.fairobserver.com/region/north_america/atul-singh-us-2020-presidential-election-joe-biden-democrats-donald-trump-republicans-news-76914/) as an example.

If you are looking for a phrasal verb, you could say that something was '[cobbled together](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cobble-together)', meaning joined roughly or hastily.

Comment: I have seen 'string and sticking plaster' - 'through the wonder of Zoom, the current situation has revealed the dreadful string and sticking plaster operations of so many law firms'; 'like a Heath Robinson contraption held together with string and sticking plaster'; 'The entire system is held together by string and sticking plaster. Expect things to go wrong more often in the future'.

Answer (score 5):

For "connecting heterogeneous pieces together in a fast and careless way to build something", I think [jerry-rigged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerry-rigged) fits pretty well:

> Definition of jerry-rigged
> : organized or constructed in a crude or improvised manner

Comment: In the UK, I think that jury-rigged came first, then jerry-built, and finally they mated and gave birth to jerry-rigged.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Supporting citation: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/jerry-built-vs-jury-rigged-vs-jerry-rigged-usage-history

Answer (score 0):

You're **slapping a bandaid on it**, as in this example from the [Dallas Morning News](https://www.dallasnews.com/news/politics/2022/02/14/children-sleeping-in-cps-offices-wont-end-unless-texas-officials-take-bolder-action-lawyers-say/):

> Texas is in danger of simply slapping a “Band-Aid” on “the ongoing tragedy” of kids sleeping in Child Protective Services offices if it doesn't take bolder steps, lawyers for plaintiff children in a long-running lawsuit said Monday.

This comes from the expression "band-aid solution":

> a temporary solution that does not deal with the cause of a problem:
>
> > Tax credits given to students are merely a band-aid solution to the rising cost of getting an education.
>
> [Collins](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/band-aid-solution)

I think both of these are mainly used in American English.

Comment: I think "slapping a bandaid" successfully conveys the meaning that the solution was hasty and superficial, but fails to convey the meaning that the solution was related to "connecting heterogeneous pieces together".

Comment: In the UK, where we tend to prefer descriptive names instead of giving free advertising, you'd probably call it a ‘plaster’ or ‘sticking plaster’.

Comment: @gidds The British have hoovered up some trademarks, or so I've heard via googling :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to what the others have noted, you can also say that it's held together with **spit and a prayer** Other very informal ways of expressing this would be that something is **jury-rigged** or **Mickey Moused** together.